# About $2\times 2$ similar matrices...

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ and $B$ be  $2\times 2$ matrices with the same trace and the same determinant. Are $A$ similar to $B$?

I know that they have the same characteristic polynomial.

So, exist $P,Q\in GL_2(F)$ and diagonal $D\in M_2(F)$ with:

$$D=P^{-1}AP=Q^{-1}BQ$$

Therefor:

$$QP^{-1}APQ^{-1}=B$$

Hence the are similar, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

---

$A =\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$ and $0_2=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$

---

$B=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$ and $I_2=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$

---

In general, when you want to disprove something implying that the matrices are similar, taking $\lambda \in \Bbb K$ and looking at the equivalence class of $\lambda I_n$ often helps because

$\begin{array}{ll}cl\left(\lambda I_n\right)&=\left\{M \in M_n\left(\Bbb K\right) \mid \exists P \in GL_n\left(\Bbb K\right), M=P\left(\lambda I_n\right)P^{-1}\right\}\\&=\left\{M \in M_n\left(\Bbb K\right) \mid \exists P \in GL_n\left(\Bbb K\right), M=\lambda I_n\right\}\\&=\left\{\lambda I_n\right\}\end{array}$

To build my two examples, I took a matrix $\lambda I_n$ and searched for a distinct matrix that would be in its equivalence class for the relation "has same determinant and same trace" (but not in its equivalence class for the relation "is similar too" since it is distinct).

Comment: Is the statement holds for nxn matrices, where n>2?

Comment: @17SI.34SA : Nope.

Answer (score 2):

No. Hint: Some matrices are not diagonalizable.